# Create Child BindingSource without immediately accessing property

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, devexpress, bindingsource

I am using a few `DataGridViews` with `BindingSources`. One of these `DataGridViews` is used to display details for a Child Property of another `BindingSource`.

The child object details are not immediately displayed on the screen (I'm using `DevExpress XtraTabControl`) and I want to load the child property only when the user displays the tab of that child property.

The child property is retrieved from the database, but as this can take a while it is only loaded the when it is first accessed and subsequent retrievals access the now cached object.

The problem seems to be that creating the `BindingSource` bindings immediately accesses the Child Property (and therefore accesses the database for every child property, and there are quite a few).

Is it possible to have Child Binding Sources only access the property when it is being displayed?

Comment: Can't you set your `BindingSource.DataSource` when handling the `XtraTabControl.SelectedPageChanged` or `TabControl.SelectionChanged` event?

Comment: That's what I had eventually went for and it seems to be working well. If you put this comment as an answer I'd be happy to mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect your BindingSource to your database at the convenient time, for example when handling the `XtraTabControl.SelectedPageChanged` or `TabControl.SelectionChanged` event.

Just set its `DataSource` property:

```
myBindingSource.DataSource=myDataSource;
```